# jQuery event collision

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object :

```
var myObject = {
    open : function() {
        console.log('Object open');

        $(this).trigger('open');
    }
};

$(myObject).on('open', function() {
    console.log('Open event received');
});

myObject.open();
```

This code throw an "too much recursion".

The problem is that trigger is calling the method, if I rename the open method, this works :

```
var myObject = {
    _open : function() {
        console.log('Object open');

        $(this).trigger('open');
     }
};

$(myObject).on('open', function() {
    console.log('Open event received');
});

 myObject._open();
```

Does this make sense for anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you created a recursive loop when you try to trigger 'open' again.
a reccursive loop is a function that calls itself over and over agains until the "stackoverflow" error happen ( no puns intended). it's a more efficient way to make loops.

on the second scenario, you trigger _open and then the function tries to trigger the 'open' event, which trigger the on('open') listener. 
simple as that.

Comment: yep i know but that is not what i expected, when I added listeners on object, i expected to jquery trigger an event, but not call the method, why this ? because if I wanna call my object's method, I just do myObject.myMethod()

Comment: Since your method is the same name as your event jquery probably thinks they are both event and when you trigger the event it trigger the function as well

Comment: It has it's little complication, but in the end it's a pretty good library

Comment: lol, yep jQuery was a great idea, but there is so many things like this that really suck

Answer (score 0):

In your first example

`$(this).trigger('open');`

recursively triggers the invocation of the myObject.open function.

In a second one

```
$(this).trigger('open');
```

triggers new custom event 'open' and then you handle this event with handler that you defined via on() method.

Comment: yes, this is the part I know, but i rly don't understand why jQuery is calling a method :)

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like your trying to create a event listener for when your function is executed?

If so this is how I have handled many of these types of events. I use custom events bound to the document so they are avaiable at a global level.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7eaoe1hp/

```
    var myObject = {
        open : function() {
            console.log('Object open');

            $(document).triggerHandler('open');
        }
    };

    $(document).on('open', function(){
        console.log('Open event received');
    });

    myObject.open();
```

Comment: yes, but I can't change my structure for a jQuery bug. My method "open" trigger an "open" event, that's all. So the only way was to create an alternative on() off() and trigger() attached to object